# What is a function in $f\in L^n(\mathbb{R}^n)$ but $g(x)=\int_{|y|<1} \frac{|f(y)|}{|x-y|^{n-1}}dy$ is not in $L^\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations

What is a function in $f\in L^n(\mathbb{R}^n)$ but $$g(x)=\int_{|y|<1} \frac{|f(y)|}{|x-y|^{n-1}}dy$$ is not in $L^\infty$. I have no idea where to start. Apparantly this is related to the borderline case of sobolev embedding but I am having a lot of trouble.

I would like a hint on how to start.

Comment: The idea is to make $f$ very large near a point, say $0$, so that it's just barely in $L^n$. Try something like $f(y)=|y|^{-1}/\log^{(1+\epsilon)/n}|y|$.  The convolution will be unbounded near $0$.